# How accurate is dermoscopy to predict if a skin lesion is a basal cell carcinoma (BCC), and if it is, whether it is superficial or aggressive form?

Tags: dermatology, diagnostics, basal-cell-carcinoma

https://dermnetnz.org/cme/dermoscopy-course/dermoscopy-of-basal-cell-carcinoma/ mentions that one can use dermoscopy to diagnose basal cell carcinoma (BCC) and their subtype (nodular, superficial, etc.).

How accurate is dermoscopy to predict whether a skin lesion is a basal cell carcinoma (BCC), and if it is, whether it is superficial or some aggressive form?

Comment: Prior research? The link you provided says nothing about dermoscopy.

Answer (score 2):

According to this https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0190962213010554, and this, https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/bjd.14499, sensitivity and specificity for BCC as a whole is pretty good. Predictive values for the different types of BCC is pretty good in some variants but not so much in others.